Running Shell Script to pass environment variable to react app and Using Nginx Template to Set Environment Variables in Docker Container
The Dockerfile is designed to build a React app and run Nginx as the production server. Additionally, it is required to run a shell script to set environment variables and use an Nginx template to pass other required environment variables to Nginx. However, there is an issue where only one of these tasks is performed at a time. The desired outcome is to ensure that both tasks are executed successfully.
# Use a base image with Node.js pre-installed
FROM node:18 AS build

# Set the working directory inside the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy package.json and package-lock.json to the working directory
COPY package.json .

# Install dependencies
RUN npm install

# Copy the rest of the application code to the workinf directory
COPY . .

# Build the React app
RUN npm run build

# Using Nginx as the production server
FROM nginx:1.18.0


#EXPOSE 3000
COPY --from=build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY ./default.conf /etc/nginx/templates/default.conf.template
#COPY api_gateway.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/
#COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/

# Copy the built React app from the build stage to the Nginx server's HTML directory
#COPY --from=build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
#COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
#COPY api_gateway.conf.template /etc/nginx/conf.d


# Entrypoint script to substitute environment variables
#COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh
#RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh

# Set entrypoint
#ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh"]

EXPOSE 80
# EXPOSE 3000

# Copy .env file and shell script to container

COPY ./env.sh /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY ./env_sample.txt /usr/share/nginx/html

# Make our shell script executable
RUN chmod +x /usr/share/nginx/html/env.sh

#CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]

# Start Nginx when the container starts
# CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"] 
# CMD ["/bin/sh", "-c", "/usr/share/nginx/html/env.sh && nginx -g \"daemon off;\""]
# CMD ["/bin/sh", "-c", "/usr/share/nginx/html/env.sh && nginx -g 'daemon off;'"]
# CMD ["/bin/sh", "-c", "/usr/share/nginx/html/env.sh"]
# ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-c", "/usr/share/nginx/html/env.sh && nginx -g 'daemon off;'"]
# CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;", "&&", "/bin/sh", "-c", "/usr/share/nginx/html/env.sh"] 
# CMD ["sh", "-c", "nginx -g 'daemon off;' && /usr/share/nginx/html/env.sh"]

# Create a startup script to run both commands
RUN echo '#!/bin/sh' >> /usr/local/bin/startup.sh \
    && echo 'nginx -g "daemon off;" &' >> /usr/local/bin/startup.sh \
    && echo '/usr/share/nginx/html/env.sh' >> /usr/local/bin/startup.sh \
    && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/startup.sh

# Start Nginx using the startup script
CMD ["/usr/local/bin/startup.sh"]


I tried various way as you can see the below commented lines, but the issue is not fixed.
So, Can someone help modify the Dockerfile so that both tasks can be executed successfully?
I tried using CMD, Entrypoint and created a shell script and called both from there. but still the issue is not fixed.
My desired outcome is to modify the Dockerfile so that it successfully executes both tasks: running the shell script and using the Nginx template to pass environment variables.
additionally i read this article to pass envirnmont variable to a build react app.
env.sh file
#!/bin/sh

echo "window._env_ = {" > ./env-config.js
awk -F '=' '{ print $1 ": \"" (ENVIRON[$1] ? ENVIRON[$1] : $2) "\"," }' /usr/share/nginx/html/env_sample.txt >> ./env-config.js
echo "}" >> ./env-config.js

env_sample.txt
REACT_APP_HOST_IP_ADDRESS=http://192.168.4.158

When we build the react app it gives us static HTML, js and CSS files.
so I am running the the env.sh file to dynamically update the REACT_APP_HOST_IP_ADDRESS when we run docker image.
In ngnix
default.conf
server {
        # URI Routing
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        #server_name 192.168.4.158;
        server_name ${NGINX_SERVER};
    resolver 127.0.0.11 ipv6=off;
    #resolver 8.8.8.8 ipv6=off;

        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html index.htm;


        rewrite_log on;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/api_ping.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/api_ping_error.log;
        ignore_invalid_headers on;
        underscores_in_headers on;

        location ~ ^/api/analytics-api/(.*)$ {
                #proxy_pass http://172.23.0.14:2345/$1$is_args$args;
        proxy_pass http://${ANALYTICS_API_CONT}:2345/$1$is_args$args;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
        }

        location ~ ^/api/(.*)$ {
                #proxy_pass http://172.23.0.3:3001/api/$1$is_args$args;
                proxy_pass http://${API_CONT}:3001/api/$1$is_args$args;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        }

    location ~ ^/socket.io/ {
                #proxy_pass http://172.23.0.3:3001/api/$1$is_args$args;
                proxy_pass http://${API_CONT}:3001;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
        }

        location / {
        #        #proxy_pass http://172.23.0.7:3000;
        #       proxy_pass http://${UI_V4}:3000;
    #   proxy_set_header Host $host;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
        }
}


running docker container (assuming nginx_ui:1 is the name of docker image)
docker run -d \
        --name nginx_ui_cont \
        -e 'NGINX_SERVER=192.168.7.109' \
        -e ANALYTICS_API_CONT=analytics_api_cont \
        -e API_CONT=api_cont \
        -e 'REACT_APP_HOST_IP_ADDRESS=http://192.168.7.109' \
        -p 80:80 \
        nginx_ui:1


The Docker Hub nginx image can already substitute ${ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE} references in Nginx configuration; beyond actually setting the environment variables, do you need more customization than that?

Hi @DavidMaze, I added some information to the question, hopefully, you will understand why I need an additional script to set the env variable

It looks like you're proxying all of your backend services via the Nginx configuration.  Can you use path-only URLs in your application – just refer to /api/whatever without a scheme or host name – and avoid needing to inject the host name?  Similarly, can you use the Docker internal DNS system and proxy_pass http://api:3001/... without needing to know an IP address?

Hi @DavidMaze, yes I am using path-only URLs in my application via Nginx (see the default.conf file), and also I am using Docker's internal DNS system. See when I try to run the docker container I am passing analytics_api_cont and api_cont. those are individual docker containers, running on the same docker network.
